# Expresion regular para pattern que solo permita letras y #, &?

Tags: javascript, html5

Ya intente con esto, pero no me ha funcionado:

```
 pattern="[A-Za-z][&]"
```

Comment: ¿Debe permitir una cadena vacía?

Comment: supongo que ya conocerás https://regexr.com/ para ayudarte a dar con ello

Answer (score 5):

Puedes probar con esta regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z#&]+$/
```

Donde:

- Lo que esta dentro de los corchetes es el conjunto de símbolos o caracteres usados para encontrar un determinado patrón en el valor pasado como argumento a la función
- Nos apoyamos del operador `+` para encontrar alguno o varios de los elementos coincidentes mas de 1 vez en el valor pasado a la función

Por ejemplo, la siguiente cadena de texto me deve devolver `false` pues contiene un elemento que no esta establecido dentro del patrón.

```js
    let cadena = "hola mundo/"
    
    let validacion = /^[A-Za-z#&]+$/.test(cadena)
    
    console.log(validacion)
```

Otro ejemplo.

En el siguiente *snnipet* deberá devolver `true` ya que todos los elementos coinciden con los valores ingresados en el patrón:

```js
let cadena = "hola mundo &"

let validacion = /^[A-Za-z#&]+$/.test(cadena)

console.log(validacion)
```

**Enlaces recomendados**

- [Regex flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)
- [Regex platform to test](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Basta con `/^[A-Za-z#&]+$/`. Dentro de los corchetes no necesitas poner OR (`|`) y los espacios los toma como caracteres válidos.

Comment: @PabloLozano agradezco mucho el comentario y ya te quitado todo lo erróneo para evitar confundir a los lectores y lectoras

Comment: Tienes razón @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'