# Solo permita ciertos caracteres especiales y letras de la a la z javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como hacer que que al insertar en un input solo me permita insertar letras entre la a y z, y los siguientes dos caracteres especiales: #, &

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer validación o quieres que te reemplace todos los caracteres que no son a-z #&?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Expresion regular para pettern que solo permita letras y #, &?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323292/expresion-regular-para-pettern-que-solo-permita-letras-y)

Answer (score 1):

Hola pues esta es una función que reemplaza el texto del input cuando el usuario levanta la tecla al estar insertando algún dato:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#texto').on('keyup', function(){
  $(this).val(validarTexto($('#texto').val()));
});

function validarTexto(texto) {
  return texto.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z\#\&]+/g, "");
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="texto">
```

Te anexo algo de [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) para que te involucres más en el tema, en este ejemplo añadi jQuery, pero se puede hacer con [javascript nativo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) Ya solo es que veas que uso le quieras dar.
Saludos.